# Node.js: Parse JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am receiving a JSON object as :

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        var obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
        console.log(sys.inspect(obj));
    });
});
```

And it prints:

```
BODY: [{"buck":{"email":"chris@example.com"}}]
```

but now I'm not able to read anything inside it. How do I get the "email" field?

Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should be doing something along the lines of:

```
http.get(options, function(res){
    var data = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end',function(){
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log( obj.buck.email );
    })

});
```

If im not mistaken.

Comment: The final call should be res.on('end', function(err) { ... }); http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/http.html#event_end_

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to get json from a server.  Is there anything in node now to shorten this... I think jQuery spoiled me $.get('url', function(d) { console.log(d); });

Comment: Is it better to use data = [] then data.push(chunk)   then JSON.parse(data.join(''))   ? since strings are immutable?

Comment: Not really, well not in V8 atleast. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299010/why-is-string-concatenation-faster-than-array-join

Comment: How can I fetch req.param after parsing? Req is not an input.

Comment: @Langdon It's totally generic - write this function once; you can use for every response, regardless of where/what it is, or what you do with it.

Comment: @János Well, you have the `req`, you made it! You also have `res.req`. (and `res.req.res.req`, and ...)

Comment: @OllieFord This is from 3+ years ago, and ExpressJS already solved the problem.

Comment: @Langdon Then if there's now a better way, consider providing the answer for the thousands of people viewing the question, and seeing only this one.

Comment: @Langdon An answer that says "use express" would not be answering the original question proposed here.  The accepted answer here is the correct way to do it if you're writing vanilla node.  But you shouldn't be writing vanilla node anymore, as there are a ton of frameworks that greatly ease development.