# Why are some of the function invocations preceded by a % in JS files for v8 source?

Tags: javascript, syntax, v8

I saw `%` in many codes. Can you explain to me its purpose or what it does?

Edit: I know the operand in math `13 % 10 = 3` but what I saw is like `return %foo`.

Encountered this while looking through [v8 source files](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5.7.228/src/js/promise.js)

Why are some of the function invocations preceded by a % sign?

```js
%CheckIsBootstrapping();
//---
// Only used by async-await.js
function RejectPromise(promise, reason, debugEvent) {
  %PromiseReject(promise, reason, debugEvent);
}
//---
var callbacks = %create_resolving_functions(promise, debugEvent);
```

Comment: Well, you could try searching for `percentage sign javascript`. That would lead you to knowing that it's a modulus operator.

Comment: `return %foo` ? Do you have a more complete example ? I don't see what that could be.

Comment: @dystroy http://stackoverflow.com/a/7299040/1365010 for exemple

Comment: That doesn't look like real javascript but some kind of dynamic insertion.

Comment: `return %foo` would throw a `SyntaxError` (Unexpected token %), so I'm curious about the 'many codes' where you encountered that

Comment: @KooiInc - See the link posted a couple of comments up. The code appears in the V8 engine source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the link you provided in the comments, the `%` character appears to be used in some of the [V8 JavaScript engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) source code to indicate a method of the C++ runtime that will be executed while parsing the JavaScript source.

For example, the line in [string.js](http://code.google.com/searchframe#W9JxUuHYyMg/trunk/src/string.js&q=StringBuilderConcat%20package:v8%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=5&sq=):

```
return %StringBuilderConcat(parts, len + 1, "");
```

When encountered by the parser, the `StringBuilderConcat` method will be executed. You can find a list of the runtime methods available to the V8 JavaScript files in [runtime.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime.h#L826) (note, I have no experience with C++, so for all I know this has nothing to do with the `StringBuilderConcat` method referenced in *string.js*, but I think it's the same thing):

```
#define RUNTIME_FUNCTION_LIST_ALWAYS_1(F) \
  /* Property access */ \
  F(GetProperty, 2, 1) \
  F(KeyedGetProperty, 2, 1) \
  /* ... */
  F(StringBuilderConcat, 3, 1) \
  /* ... */
```

As has already been stated, `return %foo` would throw a SyntaxError in JavaScript.

Comment: Minor correction: parser does not really _execute_ any code itself (with exception of `%IS_VAR` which cause parsing error if argument is not a variable). Parser just creates CallRuntime AST node (https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/parser.cc#L4720-4763). Compiler(s) then either emit call to the corresponding runtime function (https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/ia32/full-codegen-ia32.cc#L3797-3834) or inline it if it is inlinable (example `%_IsSmi`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/ia32/full-codegen-ia32.cc#L2518-2536).