# How to write multi-line paths for routing?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

Sometimes the routing path is too long so I want the path to display in multiple lines for readability.

I know the normally a multiple line string is written like this:

```
var str = 'hello \
           world \
           hi;
```

However, this doesn't work in express.js routing.

```
router.route('/:hello/ \
               :world/ \
               :hi').get(...);
```

But this works:

```
router.route('/:hello/:world/:hi').get(...);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often see people use string concatenation for this kind of thing

```
router.route(
    '/:hello'+
    '/:world'+
    '/:hi'
)
```

In fact, some JS compressors for client-side code even have special logic for concatenating these bbroken up strings into a big single-line string.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to use `Array.prototype.join`. It used to be faster than using the `+` operator, however it seems this [have changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299010/why-is-string-concatenation-faster-than-array-join) with modern browsers. Still, perhaps you prefer `,` over `+` for readability, but that's just a question of style at this point.

```
router.route([
    '/:hello',
    '/:world',
    '/:hi'
].join(''));
```