# ES6 template literals vs. concatenated strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I have the following code for [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) *template literals*:

```
let person = {name: 'John Smith'};
let tpl = `My name is ${person.name}.`;
let MyVar = "My name is " + person.name + ".";

console.log("template literal= " + tpl);
console.log("my variable = " + MyVar);
```

The output is as follows:

```
template literal= My name is John Smith.
my variable = My name is John Smith.
```

[This](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i3vgplv9/) is the fiddle.

I tried searching for the exact difference, but I couldn't find it,
What is the difference between the following two statements?

```
  let tpl = `My name is ${person.name}.`;
```

And

```
  let MyVar = "My name is "+ person.name+".";
```

I am already able to get the string `MyVar` concatenated with `person.name` here, so what would be the scenario to use the template literal in?

Comment: This is a common feature in other languages, about time! Looks cleaner, and it is multiline.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "difference", as `tpl === MyVar`? The only difference is the syntax they were created with. Notice that templates, in contrast to string concatenation, also provide tag functions which can be used for things such as automatic escaping.

Comment: You basically asking what is the difference between string interpolation vs string concatenation.

Comment: Speed difference is not worth considering - if nanoseconds is a bottleneck to you then you need to address other bigger issues, like another server etc. I prefer concat as subjectively the backticks look too similar to apostrophes which are used everywhere else.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If you are using template literals only with placeholders (e.g. `` `Hello ${person.name}` ``) like in the question's example, then the result is the same as just concatenating strings. Subjectively it looks better and is easier to read, especially for multi-line strings or strings containing both `'` and `"` since you don't have to escape those characters any more.

Readability is a great feature, but the most interesting thing about templates are [Tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates):

```
let person = {name: 'John Smith'}; 
let tag = (strArr, name) => strArr[0] + name.toUpperCase() + strArr[1];  
tag `My name is ${person.name}!` // Output: My name is JOHN SMITH!
```

In the third line of this example, a function named `tag` is called. The content of the template string is split into multiple variables, that you can access in the arguments of the `tag` function: literal sections (in this example the value of `strArr[0]` is `My name is`  and the value of `strArr[1]` is `!`) and substitutions (`John Smith`). The template literal will be evaluated to whatever the `tag` function returns.

The [ECMAScript wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20170114115928/wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:quasis) lists some possible use cases, like automatically escaping or encoding input, or localization. You could create a tag function named `msg` that looks up the literal parts like `My name is`  and substitutes them with translations into the current locale's language, for example into German:

```
console.log(msg`My name is ${person.name}.`) // Output: Mein Name ist John Smith.
```

The value returned by the tag function doesn't even have to be a string. You could create a tag function named `$` which evaluates the string and uses it as a query selector to return a collection of DOM nodes, like in this [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170114115928/wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:quasis#query_languages):

```
$`a.${className}[href=~'//${domain}/']`
```

Comment: Nice! If you had another template literal there, like ${person.message}, it would be translated along?

Comment: @Rigotti That's up to the implementation of the `msg` function. You could certainly also translate the substitution values.

Comment: @Beat The whole ecmascript.org site seems do be down. I think they had plans to abandoned their wiki anyway, so I've updated the links with archived versions.

Comment: I try to run $`a.${className}[href=~'//${domain}/']` in chrome console (and set before `className=''` and `domain=''` but I don't get the DOM nodes but array of strings :/ (in the other hadn, in jsfiddle we get error in console: https://jsfiddle.net/d1fkta76/  "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" - why?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski It's only an example for what could be possible with the new syntax, but it's not an actual feature. I've edited the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @AniketSuryavanshi Here's a comparison of template strings vs. concatenation performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083467/897024 A few years ago template strings were slower but it looks like they are a bit faster than concatenation now.

Comment: This syntax makes me unreasonably annoyed

Answer (score 39):

[ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) comes up with a new type of string literal, using the `` ` `` back-tick as the delimiter. These literals do allow basic string interpolation expressions to be embedded, which are then automatically parsed and evaluated.

```
let actor = {name: 'RajiniKanth', age: 68};

let oldWayStr = "<p>My name is " + actor.name + ",</p>\n" +
  "<p>I am " + actor.age + " old</p>\n";

let newWayHtmlStr =
 `<p>My name is ${actor.name},</p>
  <p>I am ${actor.age} old</p>`;

console.log(oldWayStr);
console.log(newWayHtmlStr);
```

As you can see, we used the ..`` around a series of characters, which are interpreted  as a string literal, but any expressions of the form `${..}` are parsed and evaluated  inline immediately.

One really nice benefit of interpolated string literals is they are allowed to split across multiple lines:

```
var Actor = {"name" : "RajiniKanth"};

var text =
`Now is the time for all good men like ${Actor.name}
to come to the aid of their
country!`;
console.log( text );
// Now is the time for all good men
// to come to the aid of their
// country!
```

**Interpolated Expressions**

Any valid expression is allowed to appear inside `${..}` in an interpolated string `lit‐ eral`, including function calls, inline function expression calls, and even other `interpo‐ lated string literals`!

```
function upper(s) {
  return s.toUpperCase();
}
var who = "reader"
var text =
`A very ${upper( "warm" )} welcome
to all of you ${upper( `${who}s` )}!`;
console.log( text );
// A very WARM welcome
// to all of you READERS!
```

Here, the inner ${who}s`` interpolated string literal was a little bit nicer convenience for us when combining the who variable with the `"s"` string, as opposed to who  + "s". Also to keep an note is an interpolated string literal is just `lexically scoped` where it appears, not `dynamically scoped` in any way:

```
function foo(str) {
  var name = "foo";
  console.log( str );
}
function bar() {
  var name = "bar";
  foo( `Hello from ${name}!` );
}
var name = "global";
bar(); // "Hello from bar!"
```

Using the `template literal` for the HTML is definitely more readable by reducing the annoyance.

The plain old way:

```
'<div class="' + className + '">' +
  '<p>' + content + '</p>' +
  '<a href="' + link + '">Let\'s go</a>'
'</div>';
```

With ES6:

```
`<div class="${className}">
  <p>${content}</p>
  <a href="${link}">Let's go</a>
</div>`
```

- Your string can span multiple lines.
- You don't have to escape quotation characters.
- You can avoid groupings like: '">'
- You don't have to use the plus operator.

**Tagged Template Literals**

We can also tag a `template` string, when a `template` string is tagged, the `literals` and substitutions are passed to function which returns the resulting value.

```
function myTaggedLiteral(strings) {
  console.log(strings);
}

myTaggedLiteral`test`; //["test"]

function myTaggedLiteral(strings,value,value2) {
  console.log(strings,value, value2);
}
let someText = 'Neat';
myTaggedLiteral`test ${someText} ${2 + 3}`;
// ["test ", " ", ""]
// "Neat"
// 5
```

We can use the `spread` operator here to pass multiple values. The first argument — we called it strings — is an array of all the plain strings (the  stuff between any interpolated expressions).

we then gather up all subsequent arguments  into an array called values using the `... gather/rest operator`, though you could of course have left them as individual named parameters following the strings parameter like we did above `(value1, value2 etc)`.

```
function myTaggedLiteral(strings,...values) {
  console.log(strings);
  console.log(values);
}

let someText = 'Neat';
myTaggedLiteral`test ${someText} ${2 + 3}`;
// ["test ", " ", ""]
// ["Neat", 5]
```

The `argument(s)` gathered into our values array are the results of the already evaluated  interpolation expressions found in the string literal. A `tagged string literal` is like a processing step after the interpolations are evaluated but before the final string value is compiled, allowing you more control over generating the string from the literal. Let's look at an example of creating a `re-usable templates`.

```
const Actor = {
  name: "RajiniKanth",
  store: "Landmark"
}

const ActorTemplate = templater`<article>
  <h3>${'name'} is a Actor</h3>
  <p>You can find his movies at ${'store'}.</p>

</article>`;

function templater(strings, ...keys) {
  return function(data) {
  let temp = strings.slice();
  keys.forEach((key, i) => {
  temp[i] = temp[i] + data[key];
  });
  return temp.join('');
  }
};

const myTemplate = ActorTemplate(Actor);
console.log(myTemplate);
```

**Raw Strings**

Our tag functions receive a first argument we called `strings`, which is an `array`. But there’s an additional bit of data included: the raw unprocessed versions of all the strings. You can access those raw string values using the `.raw` property, like this:

```
function showraw(strings, ...values) {
  console.log( strings );
  console.log( strings.raw );
}
showraw`Hello\nWorld`;
```

As you can see, the `raw` version of the string preserves the escaped \n sequence, while the processed version of the string treats it like an unescaped real new-line. ES6 comes with a built-in function that can be used as a string literal tag:  `String.raw(..)`. It simply passes through the raw versions of the `strings`:

```
console.log( `Hello\nWorld` );
/* "Hello
World" */

console.log( String.raw`Hello\nWorld` );
// "Hello\nWorld"
```

Answer (score 8):

It's a lot cleaner and as stated in the comments, is a common features in another languages.
The other thing that I found nice was the line breaks, very useful when writing strings.

```
let person = {name: 'John Smith', age: 24, greeting: 'Cool!' };

let usualHtmlStr = "<p>My name is " + person.name + ",</p>\n" +
                   "<p>I am " + person.age + " old</p>\n" +
                   "<strong>\"" + person.greeting +"\" is what I usually say</strong>";


let newHtmlStr = 
 `<p>My name is ${person.name},</p>
  <p>I am ${person.age} old</p>
  <p>"${person.greeting}" is what I usually say</strong>`;


console.log(usualHtmlStr);
console.log(newHtmlStr);
```

Comment: I dont understand if there is a major difference in having linebreaks in a string and a literal. check this http://www.es6fiddle.net/i3vj1ldl/. literal only puts a space instead of a line break

Comment: Woh, I didn't said it was a major difference. Literals line breaks are just syntax sugar. It's just for the sake of readability.

Comment: but still you pointed out a good difference. but  before accepting your answer, I will wait for some more time for a better answer which shows any big difference(if there is any! ) :)

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I am terribly sorry, but literals line breaks actually do work. Just noticed that ES6Fiddle is just a terrible way to test it. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 6):

While my answer does not directly address the question, I thought it may be of some interest to point out one drawback of using template literals in favor of array join.

Let’s say I have

```
let patient1 = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"};
let patient2 = {firstName: "Dwayne", lastName: "Johnson", middleName: "'The Rock'"};
```

So some patients have a middleName and others do not.

If I wanted a string representing the full name of a patient

```
let patientName = `${patient1.firstName} ${patient1.middleName} ${patient1.lastName}`;
```

Then this would become **"John undefined Smith"**

However if I did

```
let patientName = [patient1.firstName, patient1.middleName,  patient1.lastName].join(" ");
```

Then this would become just **"John Smith"**

General_Twyckenham pointed out that a join on " " would result in an extra space between "John" and "Smith".

To get around this, you can have a filter before the join to get rid of falsy values:

```
[patient1.firstName, patient1.middleName, patient1.lastName].filter(el => el).join(" ");
```

Comment: Actually, that's not quite correct - the `join` version will give you **John  Smith**, with an extra space. As you can imagine, this is often undesirable. A fix for this is to use `map` like so: `[patient1.firstName, patient1.middleName,  patient1.lastName].map(el => el).join(" ");`

Comment: @General_Twyckenham aah I see your point. Good catch. Also, it should be filter and not map to get rid of that extra space. I'll edit my answer, thanks.

Comment: Whoops - yeah, `filter` was the function I meant.

Comment: And according to this discussion, string concatenate is faster than array join.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299010/why-is-string-concatenation-faster-than-array-join

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tiny difference between the two: If the expression evaluates to an object that has a [`@@toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) method, that method would be called with `'default'` in the template literal version and `'string'` in the string concatenation version.

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

class C {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    console.log(hint); // 'string', 'default'

    switch (hint) {
      case 'string':
        return 'Hello';
      default: // case 'default':
        return 'Good bye';
    }
  }
};

console.log(`${new C()} world!`); // 'Hello world!'
console.log(new C() + ' world!'); // 'Good bye world!'
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

In other words, an expression inside `${}` is evaluated as though it was a stand-alone, whereas an expression used as an operand in string concatenation is evaluated with the other operand in mind.

[This section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-template-literals-runtime-semantics-evaluation) in the specs states:

> The string conversion semantics applied to the *Expression* value are like `String.prototype.concat` rather than the `+` operator.

As far as I know (and I believe I'm missing something), this means `${new C()} world!` is parsed the same as `''.concat(new C(), ' world!')` rather than `'' + new C() + ' world!'`. However, `new C()` in that expression also gets evaluated with `'string'` as `hint`:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

class C {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    console.log(hint); // 'string', 'string'

    switch (hint) {
      case 'string':
        return 'Hello';
      default: // case 'default':
        return 'Good bye';
    }
  }
};

console.log(''.concat(new C(), ' world!')); // 'Hello world!'
console.log(''.concat(new C()).concat(' world!')); // 'Hello world!'
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```