# const vs let when calling require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, io.js

As io.js now [supports ES6](https://iojs.org/es6.html) you are finally able to use the `const` and `let` keywords. Obviously, `let` is the successor of `var`, just with some super-powers.

But what about `const`? I know, of course, what "constant" means, but I was wondering when to use it (regarding best practices).

E.g., if I create a module that requires another module, I could write:

```
'use strict';

const util = require('util');

const foo = function () {
  // Do something with util
};

module.exports = foo;
```

Basically I've replaced every occurence of `var` with `const`. Generally speaking, I think that this is okay, but if I follow this pattern, it leaves me with way more uses of `const` than `let`, as most variables aren't "variables" in a literal sense.

Is this good style? Should I rather go for `let`? When should I choose `const` over `let`?

Comment: I would expect `const` to be all in caps, like `const KEY_A = 65` for example.

Comment: The way I think about it, is that a `const` should be used if the value is to never be changed, or more importantly protected from change. `let` should be used when the value is to be overwritten/changed later, and both should be used when you need a block scoped variable, and not a variable scoped to a function. If you need a function scoped variable, `var` is still available. I could be wrong, haven't really read up on ES6/2015 that much.

Comment: Declaring `util` as a `const` just means that that variable cannot be set to a different value. **However**, you are still able to add, modify, and remove properties from it if it isn't a primitive.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565056/es6-template-literals-vs-concatenated-strings

Comment: Const seems to have bad performance though http://jsperf.com/const-vs-var-mod-3

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`const` can be normally used when you don't want your program

1. to assign anything to the variable

   ```
   "use strict";
   const a = 1;
   a = 2;
   ```

   will produce `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`.
2. to use the variable without explicitly initializing.

   ```
   "use strict";
   const a;
   ```

   will produce `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

Simply put, I would say,

- use `const` whenever you want some variables not to be modified
- use `let` if you want the exact opposite of `const`
- use `var`, if you want to be compatible with ES5 implementations or if you want module/function level scope.

Use `let` only when you need block level scoping, otherwise using `let` or `var` would not make any difference.

Comment: Actually, `let` and `const` do hoist, but it is a bit more complicated than that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/3242070

Comment: I don't think the first half of this is correct. The example with `A_CONST` actually does throw an error. `const` and `let` both hoist, but are subject to the ["temporal dead zone"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let) so they cannot be used prior to declaration.

Comment: @ZachB I agree. In my defense, `const` used to behave differently in sloppy mode. [Ref](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/3152#discussion_r41552676). Thanks for pointing out, I removed the part which is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same feeling that you're describing. A big percentage of declared variables in my code tend to be constant, even objects and arrays. You can declare constant objects and arrays and still be able to modify them:

```
const arr = [];
arr.push(1);
arr;
// [ 1 ]

const obj = {};
obj.a = 1;
obj;
// { a: 1 }
```

AFAIK [ES6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) do not require variable declarations when importing, and I suspect that [io.js will move to ES6 modules in a near future](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/28).

I think this is a personal choice. I'd always use const when requiring modules and for module local variables (`foo` in your example). For the rest of variables, use const appropriately, but never go mad and use const everywhere. I don't know the performance between let and const so I cannot tell if it's better to use const whenever possible.

Comment: Why not go mad and use `const` everywhere? I've found that I very seldom actually need a `let` (mostly when I determine a value in an `if` or `switch` clause) . There is no downside to use `const` wherever it is possible and the upside of more information about the variable for the reader.

Comment: @Perseids I originally agreed with you, but [this article](https://medium.com/@PepsRyuu/use-let-by-default-not-const-58773e53db52) points out that using `const` everywhere nullifies the implied significance of `const` - that is, that you don't *intend* to modify it even though you could. I like the idea of using `const` to mean, "not only can I not perform a reassignment, I also don't intend to modify this object at all."

Comment: @rinogo: The author of the article you reference and I appear to have very different work environments and working style. A SO comment is too short to discuss in detail, but broadly, I think in const values by default all the time and reassigning a variable or changing the contents of a data structure is the noteworthy outlier for me (in local function contexts). Conversely, my work environment is not homogeneous enough in coding style that I can trust coworkers to follow the convention that `const` means "don't mutate!". But if their advice works works for you, by all means, follow it.

Answer (score 4):

Performance test `const` vs `let` usage on `require` for Node.js 6.10:

```
require('do-you-even-bench')([
  { name: 'test 1', fn: function() { 
    const path = require('path');
    } 
  },
  { name: 'test 2', fn: function() { 
    let path = require('path');
    } 
  }
]);
```

test 1 .... 2,547,746.72 op/s
  test 2 .... 2,570,044.33 op/s

Answer (score 3):

**Background:**

**let** is a successor of var keyword with imposed restrictions. These restrictions make the chances of making fewer mistakes and with added security. Basically, it has block scope i.e. it is only available to the block where it is declared. In other words, variables cannot be accessed outside the block it has been declared.

**const** accessibility is also inside block scope. But once initialized cannot be re-initialized. This can be tricky in the case of Array, Objects

What does array initialization mean?

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

`arr` contains the reference (address or pointer) of the first element of the array. That is the reason why this never holds good.

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 
if (arr1 == arr2)
    console.log("Both arr1 and arr2 are same");
```

This shall never print `Both arr1 and arr2 are same` in the console. Though they looks same in all aspects. But if we see then `arr1` and `arr2` are pointing to different locations in the memory. The same concept goes with *objects*. For example:

```
let obj1 = {name:'John', age:'22'}
let obj2 = {name:'John', age:'22'}

if (obj1 == obj2)
     console.log("Both obj1 and obj2 are same");
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are pointing to different memory locations. So the console.log statement shall never run.

If we use `const` declaration for the array or object, then according to the definition it cannot be re-initialized. But actually the identifier assigned to the array or object is a memory pointer (address). The array or object can be modified (mutated) accordingly.

**Answer to the question:**

```
const util = require('util')
```

This type of declaration makes sure that accidentally `util` is not declared the second time. This makes the code less error-prone i.e. reduce the chances of making mistakes. `const` declaration in function makes it less error-prone. As redeclaring, it throws an error.

For instance, say there is a function you declared `factorial` that is responsible for finding factorial of a number. Let us consider this example:

```
const factorial = (n) => {
     let fact = 1;
     for(let i=1;i<=n;i++)
         fact *= i;
     return fact;
}

const factorial = 5;
console.log(factorial(10));
```

Here it will throw an error. `const` makes the use of the identifier *factorial* unique. i.e. a function that takes an input and finds factorial of it.

This helps in making lesser mistakes that are very difficult to debug.

If an array or object is declared `const`, then the array or object can be modified (mutated) but any other identifier cannot use the same name that is declared using `const`.

**I hope this helps.**

Comment: Using let would also throw an error in your last example

Answer (score 0):

**const**: scope: block. reassign: not allow. declaration+initialization: must

**let**: scope: block. reassign:allow. declaration+initialization:optional

**var**: scope: global & functional. reassign: allow. declaration+initialization:optional.

According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp) use always use const is a good practice.

[image: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp]

So my preference:

1. **const**
2. **let**
3. **var**