# What is the best way to require node modules var or const?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When we are requiring node modules such as express or bodyParser we will use the `var` keyword to create a variable and assign the module. Can't we use `const` to declare such modules? That is, instead of this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

should we do this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

What is the best way? And why is that?

Comment: `const` is preferred in ES2015 code because a) it has block scope and proper hoisting behavior b) you can't modify it so yes. I would use `const`.

Comment: The new "golden rule" is: Use `const` until you can't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [const vs let when calling require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135485/const-vs-let-when-calling-require)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutability should be opt in, rather than opt out.

Whenever possible make everything `const`.