# const vs. var in nodejs require statement

Tags: node.js, constants, var

I am importing library in my nodeJS code using const or var, want to know which is a better approach and memory efficient?

Option 1:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
```

Option 2:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

Which is better? Option-1 or Option-2 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Const in javascript? When to use it and is it necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary)

Comment: That is not the duplicate of it, as I wanted to know if ```const``` can be used in importing libraries or not.

Comment: Duplicate of [const vs let when calling require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135485/const-vs-let-when-calling-require) and [What is the best way to require node modules var or const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212934/what-is-the-best-way-to-require-node-modules-var-or-const)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `const` makes the most sense here. You don't want to accidentally overwrite the library you have imported as that may lead to hard to detect bugs. Marking it as `const` will throw errors if you attempt to reassign to it (but doesn't make it immutable). Using `const` may also allow js interpreters (or compilers in most cases now) to perform additional optimisations.

Comment: is there any performance issue am I going to add when i use ```const``` ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Const should generally be faster as the engine can perform additional optimisations. Though unless you are defining millions of variables in your code the difference will be negligible anyway. Don't prematurely optimize your code as it's a massive time sink.

Comment: gotcha Thanks. Still i am not accepting your answer because I want to know which is better? If I am not getting any other answer, your answer will be accepted :) thanks.

Comment: It's purely subjective which is better. Use whichever makes sense. If the variable needs to change use `var` or `let`, if it doesn't use `const`.

Comment: Don't try to optimize code unless it actually needs it. You should _always_ favor readability and be explicit in your code. The difference between const and not const will be less than a millisecond if anything so will be completely insignificant. Focus your attention on recursive operations, deep call stacks, and loops (especially those with computationally heavy operations O(n^2) or greater).

Comment: Agreed, thanks @james Coyle. Accepting your answer now. Make sense.