# Are ES6 template literals faster than string concatenation?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, templates, ecmascript-6

Does HTML code generation run measurably faster in modern browsers when using string concatenation or template literals in ES6?

For example:

**String concatenation**

```
"<body>"+
  "<article>"+
    "<time datetime='" + date.toISOString() +"'>"+ date +"</time>"+
  "</article>"+
"</body>"
```

**Template literal**

```
`<body>
  <article>
    <time datetime='${ date.toISOString() }'>${ date }</time>
  </article>
</body>`
```

Comment: String concatenation is not slow enough that there's noticeable room for improvement. popular templaters like mustache/underscore/handlebars are dozens to hundreds of times slower than concatenation is or template literals will be.

Comment: Theoretical speaking (unless the JS is compiled), template literals would be slower since the 'string' needs to be parsed regardless of placeholder existence. The JS engine would parse the template literal once so that subsequent uses are just as fast as concatenated strings; meaning that the only difference would be the time needed to parse the template literal once.

Comment: String concatenation of course is faster. There is no parsing going on. It is just adding to the length of the string.
Still I would use template literals.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because the results are non-conclusive. 1. The speed will depend on the engine - at the very least there can be (and there *is* at the time of writing) difference between Chrome and Firefox. 2. The speed will depend on how concatenation/templates are used and with what data. 3. These can change between different versions of the same engine. 4. Microbenchmarking can produce misleading results. 5. The difference in speed, if any, is likely to be negligible. At the time of writing it *is*.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It seems for the moment string concatenation is faster: http://jsperf.com/es6-string-literals-vs-string-concatenation

```
ES6 with variable                     19,992,512    ±5.21%    78% slower
String concatenation with variable    89,791,408    ±2.15%    fastest
ES6 with function                     461,358       ±3.12%    99% slower
String concatenation with function    503,255       ±1.77%    99% slower
```

I tested was run on Chrome 43.0.2334.0 canary (64-bit), which is using V8 4.3.31, with the `#enable-javascript-harmony` flag enabled.

For reference, the latest version on Node.js (0.12.0 at the time of writing) is using V8 3.28.73: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joyent/node/master/ChangeLog

I'm sure all the possible performance optimizations that could be applied have not been applied yet, so it would be reasonable to expect performance to get better as ES6 gets closer to finalization and these features get migrated to the stable branch.

---

Edit: *Thanks for the comments @user1329482, @icl7126, Nicolai Borisik, and FesterCluck. Now that about 2 years have passed since this question was asked, ES6 browser support has greatly increased, and a good amount of performance optimization has taken place. Here are some updates*.

Edit: (February 2020) *Updated Chrome result based on @JorgeFuentesGonzález comments and subsequent confirmation*.

In Chrome (as of 59.0.3035), **ES6 string literals are faster**:

```
ES6 with variable                     48,161,401       ±1.07%    fastest
String concatenation with variable    27,046,298       ±0.48%    44% slower
ES6 with function                     820,441          ±1.10%    98% slower
String concatenation with function    807,088          ±1.08%    98% slower
```

Update: In Chrome (as of 79.0.3945), **String concatenation is faster**... See comments.

In Firefox (as of 57.0.0), **ES6 string literals are faster**:

```
ES6 with variable                     1,924,610,984    ±0.50%    fastest
String concatenation with variable    1,876,993,458    ±0.79%    3% slower
ES6 with function                     539,762          ±5.04%    100% slower
String concatenation with function    546,030          ±5.88%    100% slower
```

In Safari (as of 11.0.2), it depends:

```
ES6 with variable                     1,382,752,744    ±0.71%    fastest
String concatenation with variable    1,355,512,037    ±0.70%    2% slower
ES6 with function                     876,516          ±1.01%    100% slower
String concatenation with function    883,370          ±0.79%    100% slower
```

When using a typecast string, **ES6 string literals are faster**. However, when calling a function from the literal, **string concatenation is faster** in this example.

If you really want to go deep and need to squeeze every drop of performance out of Safari, I would suggest setting up tests that see if/how incorrectly typed variables and multiple references within a literal effect performance.

Comment: Firefox 50 64bit - ES6 has same speed as concatenation 1,423,816,207 Ops/s.

Comment: Safari 9.0 ES6 interpolations faster than concatenation about 34%
Chrome 55 still ES6 interpolations much slower
Firefox 50 the same speed

Comment: Template strings are now an order of magnitude faster than string concatenation. See version 14 of the given jsperf, it is the most accurate & unbiased one can technically get while retaining feature aspects. Version 17 is least biased but unrealistic.

Comment: The jsperf link you passed, in "Revision 1" string literals are still slower than string concatenation under latest Chrome: https://u.teknik.io/nPmY8.png

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Yup, just tested on Chrome 79.0.3945 and got a similar result to you... Really interesting, I'll update the post :)

Comment: The jsperf result file got deleted. Uploaded this one without expiration: https://u.teknik.io/02OVr.png

Comment: @AndrewOdri Just wanted to point out how much you have helped the community with this post and thank you in the name of all of us :-)

Comment: Thanks @ArturMüllerRomanov!!! It's really too bad jsperf folded though... It'll be a lot harder to collect crowdsourced data like this for future tests

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález expired

Comment: @zwcloud yep, teknik somehow changed. I've changed img hosting server since a couple months.

Answer (score 9):

I did a naive test on **node.js v6.0.0** and got **nearly the same performance**. Since the test is so naive, don't believe the numbers too much. But it seems the JIT compiler generates very optimised code nowadays. This let me decide to prefer templates over concatenation for my node apps.

For reference this is the code I used:

```
'use strict'

function strConcat(i) {
    return 'abc' + i + 'def'
}

function strTemplate(i) {
    return `abc${i}def`
}

function run(strategy) {
    let before = new Date().getTime()
    let len = 0
    for ( let i = 0; i < 10000000; i+=1 ) {
        len += strategy(i).length
    }
    console.log(len + ' - ' + ((new Date().getTime()) - before) + 'ms')
}

console.log('strConcat')
run(strConcat)

console.log('strTemplate')
run(strTemplate)
```

And the output was:

```
strConcat
128888890 - 1904ms
strTemplate
128888890 - 1979ms
```

I used `len` to absolutely make sure that the optimizer doesn't optimize the whole loop away. Anyway, it is still a very simple test. Maybe someone can make a more sophisticated one.

Comment: I ran a similar benchmark and got a similar result. My benchmark included more strings, some of which were longer. Interpolation performs slightly better than concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

Concatenation is faster and more consistent regarding its speed.
But the difference is very little for 1 or 2 variables (below .3 seconds for 100 million calls).

#### Edit

After the second run it seems that concatenation is mostly the faster of the two.

---

So, I wanted to expand [analog-nico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37037034/1950267) by providing a test that was more extensive and also looked (a bit) into scalability of the two functions.

[Code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jWtraz4h)

I decided to use four test cases for each function, having a variable in the front, one at the end, one in the middle and two variables in the middle. The basic setup is the same. I'm just using 100,000,000 iterations of the function and these iterations are run 100 times.
I used the same mechanisms to prevent optimization, namely getting the sum of the lengths of the resulting strings and logging it. I also logged the time needed (for me to guess how long it'll take) but also saved it into an array.

Afterwards, I calculated the average, minimum, maximum, and standard deviation for each method.

Here are the results:

```
{ 
  sum: { 
    t: { 
      start: 2072751, 
      mid: 2338476, 
      end: 2083695, 
      double: 2950287 
    },
    c: { 
      start: 2086059, 
      mid: 2345551, 
      end: 2074732, 
      double: 2922929 
    } 
  },
  avg: { 
    t: { 
      start: 20727.51,
      mid: 23384.76,
      end: 20836.95,
      double: 29502.87 
    },
    c: { 
      start: 20860.59,
      mid: 23455.51,
      end: 20747.32,
      double: 29229.29 
    } 
  },
  sd: {
    t: {
      start: 335.6251329981114,
      mid: 282.9490809315344,
      end: 286.2220947096852,
      double: 216.40844045461824 
    },
    c: {
      start: 255.4803356424913,
      mid: 221.48744862858484,
      end: 238.98242111084238,
      double: 209.9309074433776 
    } 
  },
  min: { 
    t: { 
      start: 20490, 
      mid: 23216, 
      end: 20588, 
      double: 29271 
    },
    c: { 
      start: 20660, 
      mid: 23258, 
      end: 20534, 
      double: 28985 
    } 
  },
  max: { 
    t: { 
      start: 23279, 
      mid: 25616, 
      end: 22887, 
      double: 30843 
    },
    c: { 
      start: 22603, 
      mid: 25062, 
      end: 22403, 
      double: 30536 
    } 
  } 
}
```

values in `t`-objects are for templates, values in `c`-objects are for concatenation. `start` means that the variable is at the beginning, mid that it is in the middle, end that it is at the end and double that there are two variables. `sum` is the sum of all 100 runs. `avg` is the average run, meaning it is `sum / 100`. `sd` [Here is the easy way out, wikipedia (simple english)](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). `min` and `max` are the minimum and maximum value of a run respectively.

### Results

It seems like templates are faster for single variables that are not located at the end of a string, considering that the average is lower and the minimum is lower. If you put a variable at the end of a string or have multiple variables in your string, concatenation is faster.

Although the minimum as well as the average of templates is better than their concatenation counterparts regarding the first two conditions, the standard deviation is consistently worse. The difference seems to shrink with more variables (more tests needed).

Since most templates won't probably be used for only one variable in a string, it is save to say that sticking to concatenation yields a better performance.
But the difference is (at least for now) very marginally. At 100,000,000 (100 million) evaluations with two variables, the difference are merely 273,58 ms, about a quarter second...

---

## Second Run

The second run looks somewhat different. Except for the maximum value, average absolute deviation, and standard deviation, every measurement proofed that concatenation is faster than templates.

The three mentioned measurements had lower (thus better) values for templates when the variable was at the end of the string or when there were two variables in the string.

Here are the results:

```
{
  "sum": {
    "t": {
      "start": 1785103,
      "mid": 1826679,
      "end": 1719594,
      "double": 2110823,
      "many": 4153368
    },
    "c": {
      "start": 1720260,
      "mid": 1799579,
      "end": 1716883,
      "double": 2097473,
      "many": 3836265
    }
  },
  "avg": {
    "t": {
      "start": 17851.03,
      "mid": 18266.79,
      "end": 17195.94,
      "double": 21108.23,
      "many": 41533.68
    },
    "c": {
      "start": 17202.6,
      "mid": 17995.79,
      "end": 17168.83,
      "double": 20974.73,
      "many": 38362.65
    }
  },
  "sd": {
    "t": {
      "start": 858.7857061572462,
      "mid": 886.0941856823124,
      "end": 786.5366719994689,
      "double": 905.5376950188214,
      "many": 1744.9005638144542
    },
    "c": {
      "start": 599.0468429096342,
      "mid": 719.1084521127534,
      "end": 935.9367719563112,
      "double": 991.5642274204934,
      "many": 1465.1116774840066
    }
  },
  "aad": {
    "t": {
      "start": 579.1207999999996,
      "mid": 576.5628000000003,
      "end": 526.8268,
      "double": 586.9651999999998,
      "many": 1135.9432000000002
    },
    "c": {
      "start": 467.96399999999966,
      "mid": 443.09220000000016,
      "end": 551.1318000000008,
      "double": 610.2321999999999,
      "many": 1020.1310000000003
    }
  },
  "min": {
    "t": {
      "start": 16932,
      "mid": 17238,
      "end": 16387,
      "double": 20016,
      "many": 39327
    },
    "c": {
      "start": 16477,
      "mid": 17137,
      "end": 16226,
      "double": 19863,
      "many": 36424
    }
  },
  "max": {
    "t": {
      "start": 23310,
      "mid": 24102,
      "end": 21258,
      "double": 26883,
      "many": 49103
    },
    "c": {
      "start": 19328,
      "mid": 23203,
      "end": 22859,
      "double": 26875,
      "many": 44352
    }
  },
  "median": {
    "t": {
      "start": 17571,
      "mid": 18062,
      "end": 16974,
      "double": 20874,
      "many": 41171.5
    },
    "c": {
      "start": 16893.5,
      "mid": 18213,
      "end": 17016.5,
      "double": 20771,
      "many": 38849
    }
  }
}
```

[The code is here](https://pastebin.com/6GcPCieJ)

Comment: I'm currently running a new version of my test script. It includes the `absolute average mean` and the `median`. It also benchmarks the runtime with 10 variables to replace.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple test with random numbers as string, both are coming so close in Chrome & FF

Testing in Chrome 58.0.3029 / Windows 10

> String literals 2,996,883 ±2.36% fastest
>
> Operator (+) 3,054,078 ±2.01% fastest
>
> Concat function 2,659,391 ±2.35% 13% slower

Testing in Firefox 53.0.2 / Windows 10

> String literals 1,923,835 ±1.52% fastest
>
> Operator (+) 1,948,503 ±1.13% fastest
>
> Concat function 1,810,857 ±1.81% 8% slower

[Test here at jsperf](https://jsperf.com/string-concat-vs-literal-vs-operator)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the benchmark above is not useful. The result of interpolation or concatenation hasn't used. So yes, concatenation is pretty fast, because no string coping there and result string have only links to the parent strings. But if you'll try out the result string or compare with another one, the string will be serialized to plane string and, yes it will take some time. So interpolation could be more effective for CPU and memory usage then concatenation in real cases.