# Why is a string template faster when it is formatted a certain way?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6

Why is this formatted string template

```
var test = `Today is $ { 
    now
}.`;
```

faster than just a regular string template on 1 line like

```
var test = `Today is ${now}.`;
```

You can see the benchmark in the *JsPerf* test linked below.

Also why does **Firefox** perform way better than **Chrome** on this benchmark?

[JsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/string-template-vs-string-concatenation)

Comment: Getting same results on Opera, strange

Comment: Because the first one doesn't have to do any interpolation on the `now` variable. The first one will print `Today is $ { now }`. The second will print `Today is Thu Jan 21 2016 ...`

Comment: Yes, you're right. The JsPerf beautify function added the whitespaces and I didn't realise it would break the interpolation. I just ran the tests, saw the results and was confused. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Uh, in the test you linked the single-line template is faster than multi-line one, not the other way round?

Comment: This is [a totally meaningless micro-benchmark](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html). Don't believe anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are ES6 template literals faster than string concatenation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055518/are-es6-template-literals-faster-than-string-concatenation)