# ECMA Script 2015 (ES6) On NodeJS Without Flags

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, string-literals, template-literals

According to [this article](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/), many ES6 functions (particularly template literals, formally known as 'template strings') are enabled by default.

The below was entered into the terminal:

```
user@host: node
> "test string: ${10+4}"
'test string: ${10+4}'
```

Even when using the '--harmony' flag, template literals are not being executed as code and are instead being treated like strings.

My version is as follows:

```
user@host: node -v
v5.7.0
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template strings are surrounded by `` ` `` (back quote) character:

```
`test string: ${10+4}`
```

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to using the back quote? I'm assuming parsing the string must take some time.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055518/are-es6-template-literals-faster-than-string-concatenation