# Are ES6 template literals safer than eval?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eval, template-literals

Template literals smell a bit like eval to me, and it's often cited that [using eval is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

I'm not concerned with [performance of template literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055518/are-es6-template-literals-faster-than-string-concatenation), but I am concerned about injection attacks (and other security concerns I may not be thinking of).

**Edit**

[An example of something that feels odd to me](https://jsfiddle.net/anthonyastige/L8d17xwa/)

```
let ii = 1;
function counter() {
    return ii++;
}
console.log(`${counter()}, ${ii++}, ${counter()}`);
```

Which outputs

> 1, 2, 3

The template literal is making side effects at the global level.  Both by a function, and directly.

**Edit 2**

[An example indicating the saferness of template literals](https://jsfiddle.net/anthonyastige/68n0Lefs/4/)

```
let ii = 1;
let inc = function() { ii++; }
console.log('Starting: ' + ii);
let input = prompt('Input something evil (suggestion: inc() or ii++)');
console.log(`You input: ${input}`);
console.log('After template literal: ' + ii);
eval(input);
console.log('After eval: ' + ii);
```

If you input `ii++` when prompted, it logs

> Starting: 1
>
> You input: ii+=1
>
> After template literal: 1
>
> After eval: 2

**Edit 3**

I've started looking into the ECMAScript specification

- [18.2.1 - Function Properties of the Global Object :: Eval (x)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-eval-x)

  - Notice it's on the global object
  - Notice the very next section is about 'Runtime Semantics' of eval
- [12.2.9 - Primary Expression :: Template Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literals)

  - Notice it's an expression
  - Notice the next section is about 'Static Semantics' of TemplateStrings

Though I'm not grokking the details, it feels like template literals are specified safer than eval.

Comment: To ask a question like this you must first understand the dangers of using eval. The dynamic danger concept is the same in other attacks too such as sql injection. What I'm saying here is that the concept is the same. It's a matter of how you use it.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're concerned about? Template literals are much more restrictive than `eval()` since all they do (usually) is evaluate the expressions and coerce the result to a string.

Comment: I've always avoided eval, and I'm just coming to ES6, so I'm not sure where to start really with the potential dangers / pitfalls of template literals. Their intended use feels safer, but are there actual restrictions in how template literals are evaluated vs eval?

Comment: Template literals are conceptually much closer to string concatenation than anything else. What makes you see them as related to eval? You could certainly construct a string from a template and eval that I suppose.

Comment: `eval` runs arbitrary strings as code. I don't think you can do this with template literals. They are completely different things.

Comment: Pretty much anything is safer than `eval`...

Comment: Compare your example to `console.log(counter() + ', ' + ii++ + ', ' + counter())`, which is the exact equivalent. Would you still consider it as unsafe?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One difference with `eval` is that template literals are parsed at compile time, while the argument to `eval` only gets parsed at run-time, when `eval` is executed.

Related to this, is that `eval` can get a dynamically built argument, while a template literal is ... *literal*: it cannot be stored as a template *variable*, which you could build dynamically, move around and eventually parse: there is no "template variable" data type. A tag function does not actually get a template variable as argument, but the parsed components of it, which are known at compile-time.

#### Some examples

With `eval` you can have this situation:

```
var code = prompt('enter some evil code');
eval(code);
```

But that is not possible with template literals:

```
var literal = prompt('enter some evil template literal');
tag literal; // there is no data type or syntax for this.
`${literal}`; // and this just gives you the entered string.
```

What is possible, is this:

```
var str = prompt('enter some string');
tag`${str}`;
```

But that does not lead to unwanted code execution, at least not worse than this:

```
var str = prompt('enter some string');
myfunc(str);
```

Any function calls must already be encoded literally in a template literal. Values of string variables cannot change that. There is no way a variable function gets called by a template literal. This:

```
`${func(str)}`;
```

...will call `func`, and that function only. It is chosen by the programmer.

#### A rather evil template literal

Having said that, this is still possible:

```js
var func = prompt ("enter some evil function name (suggestion: 'alert')");
var param = prompt ("now provide an argument for " + func);

`${window[func](param)}`;
```

But it is evident that the program *willingly* opens up the possibility to execute any function on the global object. Then indeed, you are getting close to the evilness of `eval`.

Note that the same effect is achieved with:

```
window[name](param);
```

#### The most evil template literal

As commented, then you might as well make this template literal:

```
`eval(str)`;
```

... and so the evil part is not so much in the template literal, but the generic function call you have *designed* to be in it. For that you don't need template literals or `eval`, but a bad programmer ;-)

#### On the Example

You gave this example:

```
let ii = 1;
function counter() {
    return ii++;
}
console.log(`${counter()}, ${ii++}, ${counter()}`);
```

This executes your `counter` function, but the difference with `eval` is that the string literal was already there at design time, and could not have been constructed at run-time. This code is *designed* to increment your counter, and is not essentially different from:

```
console.log(counter() + ', ' + (ii++) + ', ' + counter());
```

#### Compile Time

To stress the difference of compile/run time parsing, note that you cannot run code with a template literal that does not have valid syntax.

Compare these two scripts:

```
alert('press OK');
eval('alert("hello)');
```

and:

```
alert('press OK');
`${alert("hello)}`;
```

Note the syntax error. The first script will only notice the syntax error at run-time when the argument to `eval` is parsed, while the second script will not even run, and give the syntax error immediately.

Put more exactly, `eval` executes a new script, with its own compile and run phases. A template literal is parsed/compiled like other code.

Comment: Liked the most evil template literal :)

Comment: "The most evil template literal" should suggest `eval`, of course.

Comment: @trincot - Thanks for all the effort here! Compile vs run time is a significant point for me. I've edited my question digging deeper, but I already feel better about template literals :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is one big difference between **eval** and **template literals**.

**eval** can evaluate dynamic expressions that are not directly visible from code. This makes it dangerous, because you can evaluate any string that may come
from anywhere: client / third party / db...

However situation is different in case of **template literals**,

- because you can see full template from code,
- expressions work with your internal objects and cannot evaluate dynamic expression.

For example this will work with **eval**

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log('HELLO!');
}
    
// This will work.
var expression = 'doSomething()';
eval(expression);
```

But this will not work with **template literals**

```
// This will not.
`${expression}`;
```

You need to insert expression statically to make it work

```
// To make it work you need to insert it statically.
`${doSomething()}`;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score -1):

Template literals escape quotes automatically, if that's what you're concerned about. They also do not eval or execute anything, they convert whatever you put in to string. If you are worried about SQL Injection try doing that with template literals and you'll see they get escaped.

You should avoid using eval, unless you have a **really good reason** to use it and you really know you need it to achieve your goal. Otherwise it is **best avoided**.

Comment: SQL injection and template literals: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44086785/3345375