# Do es6 template literals protect against sql injection?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, ecmascript-6, sql-injection

Do es6 template literals, when used to construct queries, protect against SQL injection?  Can you provide some examples of common attacks and how they would be mitigated?

More specifically, I plan to use the [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) module in a node project.  In their documentation under the template literals section it says "All values are automatically sanitized against SQL injection".  Is this true purely because of how ES6 template literals work?

Comment: Do you mean XSS?

Comment: @aquinas Since OP tagged with node.js, I assume the question is indeed about SQL injections on the server side. The answer however is no, template literals don't protect against anything. They are just a 'fancy' way to build strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, ES6 template literals are just another way to build strings and don't protect you against SQL injections if you were to use them to build raw SQL queries from supplied user input without additional filtering / escaping:

```js
let name = "Robert'; DROP TABLE Students;--"; // user supplied input

let sql = `SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name = '${name}'`; // build query...

console.log(sql); // Injected SQL!
```

Comment: Gotcha.  I see now in their documentation that the template literal is preceded by the sql.query tag, so the sanitization is provided by that function from the module.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Notice the docs mentioned that TAGGED template literates gets sanitized, that tagging is nicely explained here on the other answer and also in the docs

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but only if you use an appropriate tag. When you use tags, it's called a Tagged Template Literal though. The tag goes right before the first backtick.

You can use [`sql.query` by node-mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals) as a tag or https://github.com/TehShrike/sql-tagged-template-literal

```
const SQL = require('sql-template-strings');
let name = "Robert'; DROP TABLE Students;--"; // user supplied input

let sql = SQL`SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name = '${name}'`; // build query...

console.log(sql); // Non-injected SQL!

// SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name = 'Robert''; DROP TABLE Students;--'
```

Tip! editors may automatically syntax [highlight the SQL inside the template literal](https://github.com/gandm/language-babel#javascript-tagged-template-literal-grammar-extensions) if it uses the `sql` tag.

Comment: OP asked about MSSQL.. 'sql-template-strings' doesn't support MSSQL. "... ES6 tagged template strings for prepared/escaped statements.Works with mysql, mysql2, postgres and sequelize."