# Is NPM module mssql for node.js safe from sql injection attacks if I use query with es6 tagged template literals as given below

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious, node-mssql

I have the following query I am concerned if its safe from sql injection attacks or not ?
I am using nodejs mssql (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) in node js application.

```
  //-------controller/route function in node js--------------//

   const CustomQuery = `UPDATE Students 
        SET LastName = '${req.body.LastName}', 
            FirstName='${req.body.FirstName}'
        WHERE Id = '${req.body.appid}'`
        applicationRepo.QueryDatabase(CustomQuery,this.UpdateQuery).then(result=>{
            res.json(result);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('--*--Error occurred updating--*--'+err);
        })

//-----------------------Repository-----------------//
async QueryDatabase(CustomQuery,QueryParams,QueryType) 
{
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
  {
    const request = new sql.Request();
    request.query(CustomQuery)
    .then(result=>{
      //console.log(result.recordset);
      if(QueryType=="select"){
        resolve(result.recordset);
      }else if(QueryType=="insert"){
        resolve(result.rowsAffected);
      }else if(QueryType=="update"){
        resolve(result.rowsAffected);
      }else if(QueryType=="delete"){
        resolve(true);
      }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log('---Error occured---*--'+err);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, While using npm mssql module with ES6 literals as you are already using, All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection.
Its already mentioned at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals

Comment: yes I read that part but somebody said you should use input parameters, I am not sure, if it is safe why I should use input parameters ?

Comment: You may find more views on this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086785/do-es6-template-literals-protect-against-sql-injection

Ecaping is provided by query method.