# javascript: how to avoid starting a new line in backquote?

Tags: javascript, string

Inside the backquote, if I start a new line, the printed string will start a new line as well.

e.g.

```
  winston.format.printf(
    (info) => `${info.timestamp}  ${os.hostname()} ${process.pid} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
  ),
```

will print

```
2021-Nov-30 01:27:39:2739  MacBook-Pro.local 56939 info: initializeExpress() COMPLETED
```

But

```
  winston.format.printf(
    (info) => `${info.timestamp}  ${os.hostname()} 
               ${process.pid} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
  ),
```

will print:

```
2021-Nov-30 01:27:39:2739  MacBook-Pro.local
    56939 info: initializeExpress() COMPLETED
```

I had to start a new line in the code because of code specification.
But I need to avoid starting a new line in the log message.

How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrap long template literal line to multiline without creating a new line in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321047/wrap-long-template-literal-line-to-multiline-without-creating-a-new-line-in-the)

Answer (score 1):

End the template literal at the end of the first line, and concatenate with the next with `+`.

```
  winston.format.printf(
    (info) => `${info.timestamp}  ${os.hostname()} ` +
              `${process.pid} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
  ),
```