# How to efficiently build this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of objects, e.g.:

```
[
  { a: 3, b: 2, c: 5, d: 6, e: 8 },
  { a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, d: 1, e: 2 }
]
```

Now I want to transform this to an array that contains only the values of specific properties, but without the objects themselves. E.g., if I am interested in `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, the result should look like this:

```
[ 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 5, 3, 1 ]
```

My current approach looks like this:

```
const result = _.flatten(data.map(item => [ item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d ]));
```

Is there a better (i.e., more efficient, and maybe even more readable) way to get the result?

Comment: Do you want/need to use lodash/underscore? Is the list of property names you are interested in static or dynamic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have seems plenty readable to me, and is likely efficient *enough*. But you can make it more efficient by avoiding all those temporary arrays and not looping twice:

```
const result = [];
data.forEach(item => result.push(item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d));
```

Example:

```js
const data = [
  { a: 3, b: 2, c: 5, d: 6, e: 8 },
  { a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, d: 1, e: 2 }
];
const result = [];
data.forEach(item => result.push(item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d));
console.log(result);
```

Some engines do `push` **really** efficiently, others not so much. If efficiency were a critical requirement, you'd want to experiment comparing that with this on your target environments:

```
const result = [];
let index = 0;
let n, l, item;
for (n = 0, l = data.length; n < l; ++n) {
  item = data[n];
  result[index++] = item.a;
  result[index++] = item.b;
  result[index++] = item.c;
  result[index++] = item.d;
}
```

Three things to note there:

1. Pushing directly onto the array instead of using `push`.
2. Using a simple `for` loop instead of `forEach`. The absolute overhead of using `forEach` is so small as to be virtually non-existant from a human perspective, but the *relative* overhead of it in a tight loop is quite large.
3. Declaring `i`, `l`, and `item` outside the `for` loop. If we declared them within the `for`, they'd be recreated on each loop iteration, adding overhead. (ES2015's semantics for `let` declarations are powerful and useful, but in this particular case, we don't want the overhead.)

Example:

```js
const data = [
  { a: 3, b: 2, c: 5, d: 6, e: 8 },
  { a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, d: 1, e: 2 }
];
const result = [];
let index = 0;
let n, l, item;
for (n = 0, l = data.length; n < l; ++n) {
  item = data[n];
  result[index++] = item.a;
  result[index++] = item.b;
  result[index++] = item.c;
  result[index++] = item.d;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @torazaburo: Indeed yes. That occurred to me yesterday afternoon when I was away from the computer. :-) Done now.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce with mapped keys.

```js
var array = [{ a: 3, b: 2, c: 5, d: 6, e: 8 }, { a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, d: 1, e: 2 }],
    keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(keys.map(k => a[k])), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: All due respect, that's both less efficient *and* less readable. :-)

Comment: but it is more flexible.

Comment: It is, yes. I'm just noting the last line of the question. But more flexible could be "better," just not either of the examples of "better" he mentioned. :-)

Comment: Instead of using `reduce` it's more idiomatic to write `[].concat(...array.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k])))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the desired keys from the objects in the array and merge all them with [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
let data = [{ a: 3, b: 2, c: 5, d: 6, e: 8 }, { a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, d: 1, e: 2 }],
    result = [].concat.apply([], data.map(i => [i.a, i.b, i.c, i.d]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: While this is the most readable version IMHO so far, it has the major drawback that concat creates new arrays over and over again. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, and making no claims for efficiency, you could write

```js
const input = [
  { a: 3, b: 2, c: 5, d: 6, e: 8 },
  { a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, d: 1, e: 2 }
];

console.log([].concat(...input.map(({a, b, c, d}) => [a, b, c, d])));
```

If you're really interested in efficiency, nothing would beat

```
var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  const o = input[i];
  result.push(o.a, o.b, o.c, o.d);
}
```

although as another answer points out, it would be worth benchmarking `push` against `result[cnt++] = val`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 nested forEach loops to push targeted values of each element of your input array. I propose here an function receiving as parameters initial array and properties targeted as an other array :

```js
var inflate = (data, options) => {
  var results = [];
  data.forEach(x => options.forEach(y => results.push(x[y])));
  return results;
}

console.log(inflate([{ a: 3, b: 2, c: 5, d: 6, e: 8 }, { a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, d: 1, e: 2 }] ,["a","b","c","d"]));
```