# JavaScript ES6, backticks or quotes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

Now we have the template literal in ES6 for example:

```
const str = `this is a string`;
```

or

```
const str1 = 'string';
const str2 = `this is a ${str1}`;
```

So I feel like it is more consistent to always use backticks and do away with quotes altogether. So in the above example I could instead define str1 this way:

```
const str1 = `string`;
```

I realise that this is to some extent opinion based - but is there any technical reason not to do this, e.g. is there a performance penalty for using the template literal syntax rather than the string literal (quotes) syntax?

Comment: Penalty yes or no, IMO the different literals can and should be used to signal different intent to the reader/programmer. A `''` string will not have any interpolations, so I may care about it differently than if I saw a template literal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055518/are-es6-template-literals-faster-than-string-concatenation

Comment: There are also tooling problems, as is exemplified by the obsolete code colorization of SO.

Comment: @Stephan-v it doesn't seem to answer the question which is about the cases when there's no interpolation.

Comment: Even with no interpolation, one would imagine string literals have to be faster as the engine doesn't need to check to see if any work needs to be done - but this could be a difference of microseconds. I agree with deceze, if I see a template literal I instinctively look for interpolation - this could be a difference of full seconds.