# Are there any disadvantages to using backticks (template strings) for regular strings?

Tags: javascript

I like using backticks for strings in javascript so that I can avoid the need for escaping quotes.

For example, instead of writing:

```
const s = "Anna's T-shirt says \"hello\"";
```

or:

```
const s = 'Anna\'s T-Shirt says "hello"';
```

I can use template strings to write:

```
const s = `Anna's T-shirt says "hello"`;
```

---

Is there any disadvantage to using template strings in this way?  Is there a performance cost or something else negative?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055518/are-es6-template-literals-faster-than-string-concatenation

Comment: Compatibility. https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

Comment: Most style guides will flag it if you are no using any variables in it because you are taking a hit for it to process it.

Comment: @epascarello Can you give an example of such a styleguide?

Comment: @Bergi airbnb https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#strings--quotes

Comment: If you are using babel to build an ES5 application then it is fine. If you are deploying the ES6 to production then you will have browser incompatibility with older browsers.