# Is there a performance reason to use ` instead of " and + to put strings together?

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning about ES6 and one of the new things I found was [template literals/strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). I'm used to doing this when I want to put strings and variables together:

```js
var thing = "world";
console.log("Hello" + thing + "!");
```

With template literals, the new suggestion is to do this:

```js
var thing = "world";
console.log(`Hello ${world}!`);
```

The second approach is cleaner, but is there an actual performance improvement, or is it just easier to type? Thank you!

Comment: "*is there an actual performance improvement*" [is this a premature optimisation](https://xkcd.com/1691/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are ES6 template literals faster than string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055518/are-es6-template-literals-faster-than-string-concatenation)

Comment: @igg It does! Thanks :)