# ES6 Unexpected string concatenation

Tags: vue.js, string-concatenation, eslint

```
<template>
<label>Firstname: </label><input type="text" v-model="user.firstName">
    <br/>
    <label>Lastname: </label><input type="text" v-model="user.lastName">
    <h3>{{fullName}}</h3>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'homepage',
    data() {
      return {
        title: 'Hello',
        user: {
          firstName: 'name',
          lastName: 'surname',
        },
        showName: false,
        items: [
          {
            title: 'Item one',
          },
          {
            title: 'Item two',
          },
          {
            title: 'Item three',
          },
        ],
      };
    },
    computed: {
      fullName() {
        return this.user.firstName + ' ' + this.user.lastName;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

I am trying to return a string value in `fullName()` function but when I add `+ ' ' + ....`, I get Unexpected string concatenation(prefer-template) error. If I just return `this.user.firstName;` it works. How can I return `this.user.firstName + ' ' + this.user.lastName;`?

Comment: This is not an error with Javascript, FYI. [This has to do with linting](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a lint error. There is nothing inherently wrong *from a JavaScript perspective* with `this.user.firstName + ' ' + this.user.lastName;`. However your linter is setup to show an error when it finds string concatenation. Simply use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead, as it is now the preferred method.

```
`${this.user.firstName} ${this.user.lastName}`
```

If you would prefer to use concatenation. Lookup how to modify your linters rule, for example here is how to do it for [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules) (which I believe you are using).

Comment: Why is this now the preferred method?

Comment: There are a number of reasons, some subjective others more objective. Some people simply prefer the way they look, making code to them more readable. Template literals have multi line and white space support built in. Some people claim they are more performant, which is true in [some cases](https://jsperf.com/template-literal-vs-string-plus/7). A more in-depth discussion can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565056/es6-template-literals-vs-concatenated-strings)