# Why are string templates preferred to string concatenation now?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, eslint

Came across this rule in [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template) and am not sure what the reasoning is behind. Is it faster? Less characters?

Comment: Probably just because it's more readable and less verbose.

Comment: Most of the defaults in JSLint are simply based on Crockford's personal preferences.

Comment: It's also likely to be less error prone.

Comment: Also, template literals will include literal newlines as part of the string, whereas in a normal string, you have to use `\n`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Template Literals Vs concatenated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565056/es6-template-literals-vs-concatenated-strings)

Comment: When you concatenate many values it becomes way more readable with template literals. Also you never need to escape `'` or `"`

Comment: @Isac But you still need to escape `\``, ``\`` and `${`

Comment: There are many rules in ESLint that are opinionated, some are even conflicting. That's why you can configure them.

Comment: @Bergi That is true, however thoses cases are way less common than `'` or `"`

Comment: Generally the documentation page for each rule often explains the rationale for the rule. For the rule in question [here is the documentation page](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the string in question. By popular opinion this:

```
`Hello ${name}! It's a pleasure to greet you.`
```

is more readable than

`'Hello ' + name + '! It\'s a pleasure to greet you.'`

If there are no variables or single quotes then the difference is negligible.

Comment: Good answer. Looks like this question is a duplicate. There's more info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565056/es6-template-literals-vs-concatenated-strings

Comment: I do not believe it is a duplicate, and I'm trying to get the question re-opened so I can post a proper answer, but, in my best attempt yet to be concise: enforcing template literals instead of string concatenations prevents logic errors caused by string concatenations coercing math expressions into string expressions.  e.g. ('5+5='+5+5) prints "5+5=55" instead of "5+5=10".  This can be fixed by "guarding" the math expression: ('5+5='(5+5)) prints "5+5=10", but, ESLint cannot always enforce that guarding as it requires knowing the types.

Comment: However, since template literals do not overload the + operator, math expressions are implicitly guarded in them.  Thus, by enforcing template literals over string concatenation, all such errors are eliminated.