# What does %_Arguments(0) do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, operators

Wondering why string concatenation is faster than array join, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299040/5744858) which features the following code:

```
// ECMA-262, section 15.5.4.6
function StringConcat() {
  if (IS_NULL_OR_UNDEFINED(this) && !IS_UNDETECTABLE(this)) {
    throw MakeTypeError("called_on_null_or_undefined", ["String.prototype.concat"]);
  }
  var len = %_ArgumentsLength();
  var this_as_string = TO_STRING_INLINE(this);
  if (len === 1) {
    return this_as_string + %_Arguments(0);
  }
  var parts = new InternalArray(len + 1);
  parts[0] = this_as_string;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var part = %_Arguments(i);
    parts[i + 1] = TO_STRING_INLINE(part);
  }
  return %StringBuilderConcat(parts, len + 1, "");
}
```

This is the first time ever in my life that I see that usage of the module operator. However, running `let x = %myFunction();` leads to a syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'
```

What is going on here?

Comment: That’s not JavaScript. It’s a preprocessed or transpiled language.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It is javascript with an extended syntax, namely the *allow-natives-syntax* flag used to expose some V8 intrinsics to JS code