# What's the complexity of the concat strings operator in OCaml?

Tags: string, concatenation, ocaml, complexity-theory

What is the complexity of `str_A ^ str_B` in OCaml ?

Comment: Could it be anything other than `O(n)` (assuming a reasonable implementation)? You allocate a new string, copy `str_A` to it, then copy `str_B` to it.

Comment: If strings were implemented as radix trees or something it could get more interesting though...

Comment: I think it should be O(n^2) rather than O(n).

Comment: How do you get to O(n^2)?

Comment: It might be O(n^2) in a language like C that doesn't keep track of the length of a string for you, but that's not the case with ocaml.

Comment: I’m not sure why this question got downvoted. It is focused (it even has a bunch of relevant tags!), clear, pleasantly concise, of practical interest to most programmers, the answer is not obvious (considering that plain character arrays are not the only way to implement strings, see e.g. [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29)) and is not even given by [the documentation](https://ocaml.org/api/String.html) (which says nothing about time complexities nor about the implementation of strings).

Comment: @Shawn That would still just be O(2n), not O(n^2). It would iterate over the string twice (2 * n), not iterate over the whole string for every character in the string (n * n). I can't even imagine an implementation that would be O(n^2) without throwing away most of the work.

Comment: @glennsl in Haskell for instance, strings are character *lists*, so a naive implementation of concatenation can easily exhibit a O(n²) complexity (or overflow the stack…). Of course, standard library authors know better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `O(n)`. Here's the [source code of the function](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/9ef03735ac472ea70bbc0c0bd1db784ef6201ba6/stdlib/stdlib.ml#L212-L217):

> ```ml
> let ( ^ ) s1 s2 =
>   let l1 = string_length s1 and l2 = string_length s2 in
>   let s = bytes_create (l1 + l2) in
>   string_blit s1 0 s 0 l1;
>   string_blit s2 0 s l1 l2;
>   bytes_unsafe_to_string s
> ```

The function adds the length of the two strings, allocates a new buffer using that length, and then copies both the input strings into it.

In some languages, the runtime optimizes repeated string concatenations ([for example several JavaScript implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7299010)), but I don't believe OCaml does this based on [this benchmark](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/whats-the-fastest-way-to-concatenate-strings/2616/7).